# StarUML - How to create a new line in a message argument

Tags: uml, staruml

[image: StarUML message & argument]

Instead of the message and argument going across the dotted line on each side, I would like to format the message and arguments to appear on new lines to make it neat, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Shift + Enter** to get a new line in notes, text boxes etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late to answer, however, you can enable "Word Wrap" for messages in the Sequence Diagram (Style -> Format). Since **Shift + Enter** doesn't work there.